# I'm trying to place text over image using z-index and position absolute?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position the text over image better so it displays better in a centered div. In resolutions below 1k pexels. It really needs to be displayed better for desktop resolutions.
This is my webpage template and the content in the body is centered.

[Website](http://www.156.onl.checit.info/rough/indexwithimage.html)

If you view the page below 1k pixels it doesn't display correctly I wish for it to appear over the header about 10 pixels from left.

My HTML code where it is displayed.

```
<div id="header">
  <div class="textoverimage">
    <p>New two day trip - Zoo & New Years Eve<br /> Sydney Harbour 2012. Book now to avoid disappointment.  </p>
  </div>
  </div>
```

My CSS for the above elements.

```
#header {
    height: 205px;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border-top: medium none #009933;
    border-right: medium none #009933;
    border-bottom: medium none #009933;
    border-left: medium none #009933;
    background: url(../_images/header.jpg) no-repeat;
}

.textoverimage {
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    left: 350px;
    top: 100px;
    right: 30px;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 300px;
    border: medium none #03F;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

TYVY Jared

Comment: Nothing do with your question but you might find some Lorem Ipsum useful... http://www.lipsum.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show your text over the image from left 10px 
give position: relative to parent div and left:10px to .textoverimage class and remove padding-left from paragraph p, here is the code:

```
.textoverimage{
  z-index: 100;
 position: absolute;
 left: 10px;
 top: 100px;
 right: 30px;
 bottom: 0px;
 height: 50px;
 width: 300px;
 border: medium none #03F;
 color: #FFF;
}

#header {
 height: 205px;
 width: 960px;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 border-top: medium none #009933;
 border-right: medium none #009933;
 border-bottom: medium none #009933;
 border-left: medium none #009933;
 background: url(../_images/header.jpg) no-repeat;
 position: relative;
}

p {
 padding: 15px 0;
 margin: 1px;
 vertical-align: text-top;
}
![screenshot][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGARy.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `#header` needs `position: relative;` If it's relative then you can set `left: 10px` on the `.textoverimage` and top as you wish.